# What is the domain of $A$ when it is part of the product $AB$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $m$-by-$n$ matrix. By itself, the domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the product $AB$, where $B$ is $n$-by-$p$ but is linearly dependent and has rank $1$. Now, the inputs to $A$ lie in a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is this one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ now the domain of $A$, or is the domain still $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 0):

By multiplying $A$ with the $n \times 1$-matrix $B$, you change its domain to $\mathbb{R}$. Of course the one-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, but there is no distinguished subspace. The domain of $AB$ is just $\mathbb R$.

Put in other words, any $m \times n$-matrix has domain $\mathbb R^n$. $AB$ is a $m \times 1$-matrix, hence has domain $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Let us suppose $B$ is $n$-by-$p$, but is linearly dependent and has rank $1$.